# order on exporting and importing items from MySQL

Tags: export, mysql

I have a situation here:

In my company, there is a caotic production database which has some tables, views, procedures and functions. BUT the former project managers weren't aware of designing some naming strategies to import and export easily all the items of the database, so when they use programs like Sequel Pro or Navicat, that export items in alphabetic order, it starts giving a lot of errors because there are views created after the tables they use, or SPs that use some functions that doesn't exist in the moment of their creation.

Is there a way to import and export without checking the existence of the items? or a way to create a dependencies tree and export in that order?

Our technology is MySQL, btw.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

mysqldump can handle most of the issues by creating tables for views at the beginning of the script, which will be dropped later and you can also optionally turn off foreign key checks in the dump.

There is still a known issue described [in this bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=44939), whereas a view may contain more columns than a table engine allows.